# Problem loading web pages that contain google adsense

Tags: javascript, asp.net, adsense

This may not seem like a development question but there is a link.

I have been experiencing some issues loading some web pages from my development machine. They were painfully slow. I disregarded this until I tried running my own site and found that the culprit was the show.ad.js file provided by google adsense.

Using firebug I see that the page hangs on the loading of this file and then aborts after about 5-10seconds. If I am calling multiple database records to a page it will load one, hang, abort and then load another.

Trouble shooting I have done and things I can rule out are:

- My router or any other external peripheral. If I go to any other PC in the house the page loads fine and very quickly. I have tried cabled and wireless. The problem appears to be something unique with my machine.
- It is not just my website, it is all websites with google adsense.
- I have turned off my firewall and shutdown anti virus. No change.
- It is from all browsers on this PC. I have tried chrome, safari, firefox and ie. No change.
- I do not have any ad blocker software installed that I know about.

I know there could be a million reasons why I could be having this problem but I thought someone out there may have had a similar experience. Failing that, is there any way I can trace the problem as I have no idea where to start.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your `hosts` file?  There may be a bogus IP address for the AdSense host defined there.  This file is plain text and is located at `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows boxes, with no extension.  (`%SystemRoot%` is typically `C:\WINDOWS` on a default install.)

Also, there may be a bad IP address in your DNS cache.  Run `ipconfig /flushdns` to clear it.

Comment: thank you jeffrey, you are bloody brilliant! I had a dodgy entry in the host file as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Put it as far down in the page as possible to minimize interference with rendering other elements.

I've worked on high volume sites where we would intermittently experience issues loading Google and other 3rd party js; we determined that the issue was with the 3rd party servers, not us; the only thing you can do (other than turning off adsense) is to organize the page so that it renders even if you can't load the 3rd party components.

Comment: Or, for that matter, if the user has JavaScript turned off by default.  (You get a lot less trouble from drive-by downloads that way.)  In any case, graceful degradation is a good thing for Web pages.  See http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GracefulDegradation